# Ubuntu 14.04 boot error

Tags: boot, grub2, mount

Ubuntu runs smoothly on my system but after updating it created a critical problem.
   When I start my computer its says following errors:

```
 — Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)

— Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)

— Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)

— Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)

ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell! 
BusyBox v.1.21.1 (ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash) 
Enter 'help' for list of built-in commands .

(initramfs)..
```

After typing `blkid` I got following details below :-

```
/dev/sda1 :Label="backu"  uuid="c4406f0a406fo312" 
Type = "ntfs" /dev/sda3:  Label="linux"c6e7b2c6-5e8f- 4a2d-b666-9489ef7c7c8f"
Type = "ext4" /dev/sda5:  uuid="6e0361c9- bbb6-4395-a75e-ef8d645245d0"  
Type = "ext4" /dev/sda6:  uuid="740f28da-723a-40d3-995b- 3d5dc0d30120"
Type = "ext4"  /dev/sda7: uuid="30c1ba3b- dd3e-4ec2-989b-2e3a3d0d30d8067"
Type = "ext4" /dev/sda8:  uuid="06145b6-0538-4a4b- b424-a5f7a732e8e1"
Type = "swap"
```

Answer (score 3):

Ive got the answer! Boot kernel .34 through the grub menu(hold shift during boot)then go in into Ubuntu advanced menu and boot .34. After your running .34 do enter code here:

```
sudo apt-get remove 3.13.0-35
```

Then reinstall .34 by:

```
sudo apt-get install liunx-image-generic=3.13.0.24.28
```

Then you got to set grub to boot .34 so do :

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then test your version by:

```
apt-cache policy linux-generic
```

Mine says I have none installed and 35 is recommend. If you restart and it boots you've done it!
Ignore updates until they fix .35 kernel!

Comment: This happened to me after an update and many other people too!

Comment: OMG, no up-votes? This answer has made my day!! And learned one more thing what you have said already: if I go to the advanced Ubuntu, on boot loader, and then I can choose different kernel versions to use as a base version for Ubuntu. Going through the list I have found the one that is breaking and the one that is working. I have uninstalled the breaking and wolla :)

Comment: p.s. all these files and version numbers can be found in `/boot` directory, and the file names are like `initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic` (for the latest kernel version)

Answer (score 0):

[boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) should be able to solve your problem. It can take time to run and you should back-up your data in case something goes terribly wrong. It should however work just fine and you'll be back up and rocking Ubuntu :)