# Booting: How to use rootdelay parameter in grub. Trying to ensure a menuentry works without wait errors

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel, mount

I seem unable to make the grub booting wait and spend more time looking for the target partition.
**What am I doing wrong?**

Some solutions involve use of ***rootdelay*** being set or increased from Grub's menuentry.
For instance  [Q.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361886/cannot-find-root-device-after-latest-kernel-upgrade) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15515/disk-by-uuid-not-detected-initramfs-boot-failure) with a mention of a typical error and the procedure:

> ... list of parameters. Add this one to it: rootdelay=130
>
> Hit Enter and then b (boot)

I am trying to use this method, [I used [F10] not [b]] , but although I get a code prompt I am not actually seeing any obvious rootdelay  i.e.  a delay in the time before the prompt appears whilst increasing the time available to look for the target.
I have been trying with a value of 30 which I expect to result in a very noticeable 30 seconds delay.

I also have an issue with trying to get a read write system mounted and working, but will post that as a separate question.

Maybe I am making some novice error with syntax or something, although I have previously had similar methods working without problems.  I have separated the  `rootdelay=30` with leading and trailing spaces, used all lowercase, and entered my chosen value immediately after the equals character.

The back story to this is that I have a Ubuntu install on a multiboot amd64 bit laptop that will get a login screen, but I appear to have forgotten the password and am trying to use `passwd` in `rw`mounted mode to reset it. [Other Operating Systems correctly boot, login and run as expected.] I tend to get error messages about delays similar to

> — Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
>
> — Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)

Not sure how I get the actual messages to post here as the system is not at that point in RW mode so I can only copy by eye, rather than pasting or echoing.

Right now I do not seem to need the rootdelay, but I do want to figure it out for when I do need it.  As for the lack of a password reset, at least I can access the home partition of the Ubuntu I can't login to and any important data should have been backed up anyhow. So at present this issue is a minor irritation rather than a data loss issue.

==> EDIT
I have now discovered one method to get in to RW mode by remounting from the Command Line obtained as above.
From the new prompt I enter:  `mount -o remount rw  /` 
That results in `EXT4-fs (sda6): re-mounted. Opts: (null)`

That still will not give me the desired `passwd` command

When I exit it results in a kernel panic.

BUT it does enable me to make a persistent write to the hdd which I can see later. i.e I may create new files in the root that are visible

end edit <==

Related external documentation is

- Community Wiki [Fixing reboot/shutdown freezes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Fixing_reboot.2Fshutdown_freezes%5D) Which indicates an alternative more permanent method of passing parameters, instead of directly editing Grubs menuentry. But unfortunately does not specifically mention the rootdelay parameter.
- kernel.org  although I quickly get out of my depth looking at that site https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html includes

  ```
     rootdelay=      [KNL] Delay (in seconds) to pause before attempting to
                   mount the root filesystem
  ```

I would be glad of any tip or pointers as what to do or try next.